# How to persist IAUthenticationFilter result between requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

While implementing a custom IAuthenticationFilter, I end up having the below code:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationAuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal principal;

            // logic to retrieve the claims principal

            filterContext.HttpContext.User = principal;
            filterContext.Principal = principal;
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        }
    }
}
```

For a reason I can't grasp, I have 2 issues with this implementation:

1. The `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always `false`. Therefore, I always re-run my custom logic to authenticate users.
2. As soon as I go to a page that has a controller decorated with another Authentication action filter attribute (e.g. `Authorize`), the security principal is "lost" and the re-show the the "register" and "Login" links.

I strongly believe that I am not persisting the identity correctly, but I can't figure out the right way. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should save reference of your prinicipal to a cookie. Or you should run your logic to retrieve the claims principal for every request.

I don't familiar with claims-based identity, but anyway

```
filterContext.HttpContext.User = principal;
filterContext.Principal = principal;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

is not enough to save autorization in web-application, because filter context and http context is exists for one request. I'm not sure about Thread, but for me it is not a good place to store principal in web application.

Comment: Your probably right. I managed to get rid of the first issue by saving the principal into the session and testing if it's already present on subsequent requests. However, the second part of the issue remains I strongly believe that there something wrong with this approach. The way the filter saves the identity should be "understandable" by the rest of the application.